# Is there any fix for blocks above y-128 not being visible with a >16x texture pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently discovered that, from below y-level 128, I couldn't see any blocks above y:128. After some experimenting, I found that the cause was the 64x texture pack I was using. With any texture pack larger than 16x, I cannot see blocks above y:128. Is there any fix for this? I am using Optifine 1.4.5 HD U D3 to provide the enhancements necessary for a >16x texture pack.

Comment: note that up-down is called y (as seen in the f3 debug screen) you might wish to edit that is that is the case

Comment: What version of Minecraft and Optifine?

Comment: @ratchetfreak - Oh, right. I've been playing Dwarf Fortress too much!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - Minecraft 1.4.5 and Optifine 1.4.5 HD U D3

Comment: Thanks; more information, more good. :) (FYI, my own guess—but only a guess—is that it's an Optifine bug and the most productive course of action would be to report it to the Optifine team.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie - It's not an Optifine bug. Just remembered that I tried disabling optifine and I still had the same issue. I was a little tired when I made this question, and didn't think of that.

Comment: Then my guess definitely didn't deserve to be an answer! :) I'd still guess it's a bug, just in Minecraft itself then, probably something that was overlooked when the code for Anvil went in.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yep, I'm sure that's it, I was just hoping someone had found a fix.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct fix; the bug resides within the high-res texture mod itself. I, too, have experienced this similar bug; it doesn't have anything to do with MC iirc.

Comment: @Qix - Would using MCPatcher instead of Optifine fix it?

Comment: @SaintWacko iirc MCPatcher just patches the client; optifine is actually a mod. So that's like comparing apples to oranges.

Comment: The problem was solved in the most recent version.

Answer (score -1):

Try updating your minecraft to the newest version and this may fix the problem.

Comment: Are you aware that this question is about a year old?

Comment: Yes the purpose is to contribute to the site so other can see the solutions not just for gaining reputation.